# Getting Message History

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to use PowerShell to get the date of the last message submitted to a Team's chat.

Looking around, I found [this](http://windowspbx.blogspot.com/2018/04/microsoft-teams-use-powershell-to-check.html) blog post, which indicates that I should be able to use the LastModifiedTime property (using Get-UnifiedGroup and Get-MailboxFolderStatistics), but in my case, that value does not represent the date of the last post (it is off by more than a year).

How can I actually get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the -IncludeOldestAndNewestItems parameter in Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics cmdlet. That seems to be reporting the correct data (in NewestItemReceivedDate).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling [List channel messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) graph API. This should return the list of messages in the channel with timestamp.

You can pick the latest message from the list. Usually the first one in the list is the most recent one.